# cloud-init queries DHCP

Tags: cloud-init, preseed

We are running a preseeded Ubuntu installation from disk using ubuntu autoinstall (https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall)

Since upgrading to 20.04.6, we are facing issues when the cloud-init mechanism detects a DHCP server on the network, which crashes the installation.

Is it possible to disable any networking during cloud-init?

Our grub.cfg looks like this:

```
menuentry "custom install " {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud/ ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to disable cloud-init networking using the kernel cmdline, add:

`network-config=disabled`

Documentation for disabling network-config in cloud-init can be found at https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/network-config.html#disabling-network-configuration